# Am I doing correct unit test before whole batch training?

Tags: neural-networks, multilabel, image-segmentation

I read somewhere that unit tests are important before jumping onto training for the whole batch. And for that reason, if [one sample overfits](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607#:%7E:text=Start%20with%20a%20really%20small%20dataset%20(2%E2%80%9320%20samples).%20Overfit%20on%20it%20and%20gradually%20add%20more%20data.) on the model, can we decisively say that the training will work?
I wanted to apply this basic knowledge to understand if my train algorithm works or not. I am trying to perform multi-label segmentation. And using 3D patches to train in a one-hot encoded method. Using the following hyperparams:
Network: `U-Net`
Loss function: mixed `Generalized Dice` and `Focal Dice`
Optimizer: `Adam`
I tried to overfit only one patch and trained it for `200` epochs. (which doesn't take even 20 minutes)

As it can be seen, some labels reach nearly 90% dice and some stay at the bottom: `Bone`, `TP` and `EB`.
`TP` and `EB` are smaller anatomy labels but it performed well when I try to train with lower number of anatomy labels.

Is there anything wrong with the training? The `mean dice` doesn't improve much after ~130 iterations. Does it mean there is not enough data to learn(since only one sample is being shown)? If so why isn't it overfitting?

Could anyone help me understand?

[image]